# Knockout rendering nestled lists when depth is unknown

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to render a nestled list with knockout.js but my problem is that I don't know how many levels of child-objects I have before hand in a object. It could be none, one or three hundred levels of grandchildren.

This is an example of what I have when reading from only one level of the list:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'friendTemplate', foreach: friends, as:  'friend' }"></ul>

        <!-- Template -->
        <script type="text/html" id="friendTemplate">
            <li>
                <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong>
                id: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>,
                parentId: <span data-bind="text: parentId"></span>
            </li>
        </script>

        <script type="application/javascript">
            function friend(id, parentId, firstName, lastName) {
                this.id = id;
                this.parentId = parentId;
                this.profilePicture = "";
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.friends = ko.observableArray();

                this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
                    return firstName + " " + lastName;
                });
            }

            function userViewModel(id) {
                this.id = id;
                this.profilePicture = "";
                this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert"); 
                this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
                this.friends = ko.observableArray();

                this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
                    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
                });
                this.addFriend = function() {
                    this.friends.push(new friend(-1, this.id, 'John', 'Doe'));
                }.bind(this);
            }
            var user = new userViewModel(1);
            ko.applyBindings(user);

            var friend1 =  new friend(0, user.id, 'Patty', 'Smith');
            friend1.friends.push(new friend(0, user.id, 'Henry', 'Bellard'));

            user.friends.push(friend1);
            user.friends.push(new friend(1, user.id, 'George', 'Maddison'));
            user.friends.push(new friend(2, user.id, 'Takashi', 'Hendrixsson'));
            user.friends.push(new friend(3, user.id, 'Bella', 'Suffeur'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the first friend in the list also has a friend and in theory this friend could also have a friend.

So how can I render these friends when I don't know the level of nestling? Do I have to add these elements dynamically with JQuery or some such?

Comment: so theres a very nice example about unobstrousive knockout http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use recursion to solve this problem. You need to add another ul inside the li that uses the same template:

```
<!-- Template -->
<script type="text/html" id="friendTemplate">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong>
        id: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>,
        parentId: <span data-bind="text: parentId"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'friendTemplate', foreach: friends, as:  'friend' }">       
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7dr/11/